# Unclear c++ return type to python expression

Tags: python, c++

I'm trying to understand a C++ to python interface:

in [g2p.py](https://github.com/sequitur-g2p/sequitur-g2p/blob/master/g2p.py) from line 170 there is this code (cleaned for clarity):

```
nBest = translator.nBestInit(left)
logLik, result = translator.nBestNext(nBest)
posterior = math.exp(logLik - nBest.logLikTotal) // ***This is the line in question***
print('%f' % (posterior))
```

which uses [sequitur.py](https://github.com/sequitur-g2p/sequitur-g2p/blob/master/sequitur.py) from line 759:

```
def nBestInit(self, left):
    left = self.sequitur.leftInventory.parse(left)
    result = self.translator.nBestInit(left)
    result.thisown = True
    result.logLikBest = self.translator.nBestBestLogLik(result)
    result.logLikTotal = self.translator.nBestTotalLogLik(result)
    return result

def nBestNext(self, nBestContext):
    logLik, joint = self.translator.nBestNext(nBestContext)
    joint = self.unpackJoint(joint)
    left, right = self.jointToLeftRight(joint)
    return logLik, right
```

In this script LogLik is defined in [Probability.hh](https://github.com/sequitur-g2p/sequitur-g2p/blob/master/Probability.hh) and translator functions 
 in [Translation.cc](https://github.com/sequitur-g2p/sequitur-g2p/blob/master/Translation.cc). `nBestTotalLogLik` & `nBestNext` both return class type `LogProbability`. `LogProbability` has various overloads non of which return a numerical type, e.g.:

```
inline LogProbability operator-(const LogProbability &lhs, const LogProbability &rhs)
```

My question is, in line `math.exp(logLik - nBest.logLikTotal)` how is the expression `logLik - nBest.logLikTotal` evaluated as numerical for exp() to process?

Comment: In the definition of `LogProbability` you have "`typedef double BaseType;`". I'd assume, then that *somewhere* there is code that uses `BaseType` to come up with a map of C++ types and their matching Python types. I only looked at the code briefly and didn't find such conversion, but I'd assume python interprets `LogProbability` as it would a C++ `double`.